Would the question be better here?

 I'm confident you could write a Question about this suitable for
Math.SE, but it would be expeditious to have a look at sister site
CrossValidated (stats.se). Tags should be a secondary concern.

I asked whether I could ask a question on which is the maximum entropy probability distribution and was told to take a look here.
Should I ask here, what tags should I use,
probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, estimation?

Have you searched our site for existing answers?  Try maximum entropy distribution moment for instance.  It's also worth noting that the question as you have framed it might be both overly complex and too limited, because "given support with location and scale parameters" implies the support is all real numbers.  Without some constraints (such as moment constraints), there is no maximum entropy solution.

@whuber I don't undestand what you mean moment constraints. Moments as I understand them include the mean and the variance (central moments). I want a distribution (a family actually like Normal and Uniform are both families containing diferent distributions for different parametre values). I want the family that is the maximum entropy for given Support($\Omega$), Mean (transformation of $\mu$) and Variance (tranformation of $\sigma$). A Uniform distribution is a special/limiting case of the above (when the support, mean, variance of the Distribution in question and the Uniform are the same).

Both the mean and the variance are moments.

@whuber So I don't undestand what are these constraints you are talking about. Are there moment constraints for a normal distribution? If so the same is true for the distribution I am looking for. If anything there are more constraints here than for the normal. The mean has to be inside the Range (between a the minimum and b the maximum) and the variance has a maximum depending on the specific support and specific mean.

For a given mean and variance, the Normal distribution is the maximum entropy solution.  The general problem is addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395996.

@whuber The normal distribution doesn't have the given support part. All Distributions in the family are continuous and are supported from negaive infinity to positive infinity. I have a different set of constraints. I allow for any possible support. Is the maximum given by $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,\Omega) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ Where $\Omega$ are all the values in support? In the continuous case the Sum below becomes an Integral and we can have a Mixed Case with various Sums and Integrals

Please, please, read and study the references: they provide useful information.

@whuber I already have. Please don't doubt I have read the references. I don't find them relevant.

@whuber Maximum entropy principle helps you find the distribution with the highest entropy (most uncertainty, least biased) among all distributions that match first n sample moments. As you mentioned, the maximum entropy distribution for
is a Gaussian distribution

@whuber The thing is I am not interested in having the highest entropy between distributions (only) with the same mean and sama variance alone. There is an additional constraint. Same support (also, additionally). So I am looking for the highest entropy among all distribuitons with same mean, same variance AND same support.

I'm done here.  There is an adage in English about leading horses to water.

@whuber But you haven't been leading me to water. I have earnestly read the references. An analogy woulf be that you didn't lead me to water but to a wastebin. I have read the references. And I have searched for existing answers.

You are veering into offensiveness, which is inappropriate here (or, really, anywhere else).  It reduces your chances of being understood or enlightened.

@whuber It wasn't me who started with adages. I have read and searched.

@whuber I apologize for offending you. It was not my intention.  Substitue waste for champagne. Still not water. It might be Field's Medal material but still not what I asked. You didn't lead me to water. Still I read it. I just din't quench my thirst because it wasn't water.

@whuber To correct a misunderstanding. Given support does not imply that the support is all real numbers. I can't imagine how it would either. Given support is like given mean, given variance. It can be anything but is not (at the same time). It can be any interval, set of points, whatever in the real line (like the support of all the distributions in the uniform family).  The uniform distribution on the interval [a,b] is the maximum entropy distribution among all continuous distributions which are supported in the interval [a, b]. So I am looking for a maximum entropy with both constraint set

@whuber https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Uniform_and_piecewise_uniform_distributions for any specified support the maximum entropy is simply given by a Uniform Distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Specified_mean_and_variance:_the_normal_distribution for specified Mean and Variance the maximum entropy distribution is the Normal Distribution, What happens when one puts both constraints together? That was my question

The maximum entropy distribution, for a specified mean and variance simply remains proportional to $\propto e^{ax+bx^2}$ for any support. For weird supports it just means that it becomes tricky to compute $a$, $b$ and the normalisation constant. A related question that seeked for a maximum entropy distribution for a given mean and variance with a support different from the real line is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500094/

If there are any troubles with this meta question, then I guess it might be better to ask it in a question where it is easier to present the problem/question in more detail. The comments here are confusing.

@SextusEmpiricus Which was my question. And you wrote the answer which I accepted and I awarded the bounty. Since we don't want to satisfy anymore the first 4 conditions (e.g belonging to the Exponential Family, Being unimodal, monotonic) can't we go any higher than $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,\Omega) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ we no longer want to discretisize the truncated normal we just want the Maximum Entropy for any specified support (keeping the mean and variance constraints).

Ah @GeorgeNtoulos , I referred to that other question, and I didn't realise that you are the very same person that asked that other question.

For the maximum entropy distribution with a given mean and variance it is very simply $\propto e^{ax+bx^2}$. More difficult is to compute $a$,$b$ and the normalisation constant.

@SextusEmpiricus So the maximum entropy distribution belong to the Exponential Families? The Exponential Family distributions always have maximum entropy for given mean and variance? Is the Uniform Distribution a limit? What happens when the mean and the variance of the distribution in question coincides with that of the Uniform on the same support?

@GeorgeNtoulos I can imagine that the case of the variance and mean being the same to that of the uniform will mean that the uniform is the maximum entropy distribution (with or without the constraints). The uniform distribution is a member of the family of normal distributions (and it is at the limit with infinite variance) and requires less restrictions to be the maximum entropy distribution. So, yes if a member from the family of maximum entropy distributions without a specific constraint happens to fullfill more specific constraints, then that member is the maximum entropy distribution.

@SextusEmpiricus The Normal distribution supported on the entire Real Line is limited by the Uniform (a degenerate Normal would look like a Uniform distribution). But what happens with a specific support when a Uniform Distribution can be well defined with finite variance? Is it also a limit of all Exponential distributions with the same Support, Mean and Variance?

@GeorgeNtoulos , the uniform distribution has a finite variance. There's no need for infinite variance.

@SextusEmpiricus No need to state the obvious. I stated so first didn't I? I didn't ask for confirmation I don't understand why you stated what I did first? I asked about a finite support. What happens when the distribution you say (proportional e^(ax+bx^2))  has a mean and variance equal to the Uniform distribution on the same support.

@GeorgeNtoulos repeating myself: "So, yes if a member from the family of maximum entropy distributions without a specific constraint happens to fullfill more specific constraints, then that member is the maximum entropy distribution" improving the last part of that sentence a bit: ...then that member is also the maximum entropy distribution for the case with more specific constraints

@SextusEmpiricus That is the only part I lost you. I don't understand what you say.

@SextusEmpiricus A member A is the B distribution. Where A= from the family of maximum entropy distributions and B maximum entropy. I don't understand what you are talking about and how is that related to my question what happens when in the distribution in question the mean and variance are those of a uniform. No constraints become more specific. The constraints remained the same (Specified, mean, variance and support) but the mean and variance assumed a numerical value. Let's say for the 0,1 discrete Uniform, mean=0.5 and variance=0.25.

In $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,\Omega) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$ when $\Omega$ includes only 0 and 1 (the support) the mean (and $\mu$ actually since it happens to be symmetrical) is 0.5 for the variance is 0.25 only as a limit as $\sigma$ approaches positive infinity. I don't see any relation of what you repeated with my question if the Uniform is included (as a limit) in the family. And what happens since it is only a limit?

@GeorgeNtoulos I have already commented too much. This conversation is getting long winded. Get your answer properly with a question. Comments and chat aren't good for this.

Imo, the question suits better here. Potential tags could be distributions, estimation etc.

A plain yes is uninteresting. Why would it be so much better to ask here?

For that matter, you can ask that at Maths. But the problem you seemed to be describing itself suggests it is more suitable here as you may get much better insight, than you can speculate beforehand. I am not guaranteeing you that you will get a definite answer but the statistical insight goes beyond the mathematical prospects which tilts its appeal here rather than at Maths, imo, of course.
